# Magento : Selectively applying the extra fee to the total

Tags: magento

I'am doing a module for adding extra fee.
I have defined a custom total collector as

```
    <sales>
       <quote>
          <totals>
             <fee>
               <class>fee/sales_quote_address_total_fee</class>
             </fee>
          </totals>
        </quote>
    </sales>
```

This collect() and fetch() methods are also defined and it is working. My question is ; is there a way I can selectively add the extra fee i.e only when user checks a checkbox.

Pls help I'm quite new to magento.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is perfectly possible. You can try [Magento Extra Fee](http://www.magikcommerce.com/magento-extra-fee-extension) extension which has an option for creating extra product fee. This fee can be mandatory or optional. Mandatory fee will get automatically added to cart when product is added to cart. Optional fee will be shown to customer with checkbox for selection. I hope this is what you are looking for.